# Place a "col-lg-12" in a responsive container using

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to place Bootstrap breadcrumb navigation in a template.

What I would like is a full-width 100% with a background color, and then within that place a `col-lg-12` but I can't figure it out.

This image might help:

[image]

```
<div class="container-fluid darkgrey">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="<?php echo get_option("siteurl"); ?>">Home</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item">Section</a></li>
                    <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page"><?php the_title();?></li>
                </ol>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I think I might need to "nest" columns but I can't figure it out.

Am I on the right path? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[Read the docs, Luke](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/overview/) :-)

> Use .container-fluid for a full width container, spanning the entire width of the viewport.

You are using `.container-fluid`, so you get a fluid, 100% width container.  Use `.container` to get a fixed with container.

[Here's a workig JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dont_panic/5hf71opu/).

Also note you have an unbalanced `</a>` after `Section`, maybe just a copy-paste error here on SO.

Comment: The reason why OP uses a `.container-fluid` is because they want the background to span the entire width of the page. Your answer breaks that. The correct answer is to place a `.container` in between the `.container-fluid` and the `.row`, not to replace `.container-fluid` class with `.container`.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu Unless I a missing something, that seems like an over the top complication for no reason ... why not simply use `<body>` for the outside style?  I've updated my JSFiddle.

Comment: ... or any container element, `<section>`, `<div>`, etc, or yes even a `.container-fluid`.  My answer does not "break" that, it just shows the nav element.  I assumed the rest was obvious, my mistake.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu The code I've provided is a drop-in replacement for the chunk of code OP has shown.  Nothing more.  OP already has it nested in something, even if that something is just the `body`.  It seems misleading to me to suggest it must be nested inside a `.container-fluid`, as that's simply not true.

Answer (score 0):

To align the contents to `.content` width while keeping section background full-page width, you could nest a `.container` inside your `.container-fluid`:

```css
.darkgrey {
  background-color: #e9ecef;
}

.darkgrey .breadcrumb {
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding: .75rem 0;
}
.darkgrey + .container {
  padding-top: .75rem;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid darkgrey">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
          <ol class="breadcrumb">
            <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href>Home</a></li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item">Section</li>
            <li class="breadcrumb-item active" aria-current="page">
              Test Post 3
            </li>
          </ol>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-12">
      <h2>Test Post 3</h2>
      <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet... </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Important note: `.container`s can be placed inside `.container-fluid`s but should not be placed inside another `.container`.
Another note: you probably don't need the CSS (from the screenshot it looks like your theme already handles that part, but I needed it on SO).